# run-program in clozure common lisp do not show GUI window

Tags: common-lisp, subprocess

I am using ccl under win7 OS, I call `run-program` function in ccl console like this:

```
(ccl:run-program "notepad.exe" () :wait t)
```

After that, I can find the "notepad" process in the process list from "task manager", and ccl blocks to wait for "notepad" process to exit. But the GUI window of notepad do not show. It seems that the notepad is just running under background.

I am not sure whether I miss any parameter to "run-program", does anyone meet the same problem?
Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem under Windows Vista. 
My temporary workaround is to start a batch file, which contains the program to be started.

Eg C:/tmp/notepad-starter.bat contains:

```
notepad.exe %1
```

..which allows me to type

```
(ccl:run-program "C:/tmp/notepad-starter.bat" '("C:/tmp/notepad.pl") )
```

...which works fine and starts the notepad.exe process including the GUI.
You even could dynamically create the batch file from out of Lisp first before starting it.

Answer (score 0):

I found an even easyer way: 
create a batch file called eg. generic-batch-starter.bat
which contains just %1 %2 %3 %4

You then can call executables as part of the parameter list:

(ccl:run-program "C:/tmp/generic-batch-starter.bat" '("notepad.exe" "textfile.txt"))

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Windows 7 to make the notepad window visible

```
(ccl:run-program "cmd.exe" '("/c" "notepad.exe") :wait nil)
```